# How to close Spinner drop down when other parts are selected android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a ViewPager with fragments and there is a spinner in each one of them. When I open the spinner and swipe the view pager, the drop-down won't disappear!

How can I close the spinner drop down on page swipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close the spinner while swiping using viewpager's `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` listener. According to the [github.com/skydoves/PowerSpinner](https://github.com/skydoves/PowerSpinner), you can call `powerSpinnerView.dismiss()`.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        powerSpinnerView.dismiss()
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you implement your spinners?
Try implementing `onFocusChangeListeners` to your views. That should fix your issue.

Comment: Can u help me more in advanced? I've used https://github.com/skydoves/PowerSpinner for a better view!